# What regular expression needed to extract a part from a text to include splitting points too?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

heres is the code where I get strings from a textbox:

```
string txtS = TextBoxS.Text;
```

than extract some text with regex:

```
string[] splitS=Regex.Split(txtS, @"\s(we|tomorow)\s");

text: Today we have a rainy day but maybe tomorow will be sunny.
```

Now after splitting this gives me an output within a splitting point
OutPut:  have a rainy day but maybe

But what regular expression to use to get an output including the splitting points or delimiters, `so I want this output: we have a rainy day but maybe tomorow`   I tried some other regular epressions but didn`t find the proper one....

Comment: Try to match and extract the value of the group with `\s(we.+tomorow)\s`. See the example in the regex tool here: https://regex101.com/r/ZVBnZQ/1

Comment: I tried it adding points or plus sign but didn`t work...

Comment: Would it be possible that `tomorrow` and `we` appear in a different order or even multiple times? What would you expect then?

Comment: Try the example in the regex tool it works. I tried to execute the generated C# code and the console displays the correct answer expected in your post. You have to MATCH and not SPLIT with that regex. However if the order of WE or TOMOROW is different then the regex would not obviously be the same.

Comment: different order is okay so how would I extract: "we have a rainy day but maybe " only?

Comment: To extract only `we have a rainy day but maybe` you can match the input string with the regex `\s(?:(we.+)tomorow)\s`.

Answer (score 0):

The C# code would be :

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\s(we.+tomorow)\s";
        string input = @"Today we have a rainy day but maybe tomorow will be sunny.";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that I use words as delimiter too where I only extract the text without delimiters and I need the other part where I include the delimiters too... so need both of them combined?

Comment: Yes, if you use `Regex.Split()` you should store the results in another array or list variable and add (meaning **prepend** and **append**) the delimiters. If you use `Regex.Matches()` you'll probably have the delimiters among the matched results like shown in my answer above.